# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.log4j.Logger.info(Object)

Tags: maven, selenium-chromedriver, log4j

facing issue in log method while running selenium script.

1. I have attached the log4j maven repository in the pom file.
2. log4j setting file is also attached in the home director

can anyone help me out with why getting this error?
**error**

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.log4j.Logger.info(Object)" because "blocknet_maven_hybird_framework_v1.testcases.TC_login.logger" is null.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver () ;
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TC_login.class);
    PropertyConfigurator.configure ("Log4j.properties") ;
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3000,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }



login_page lp = new login_page( driver ) ;
    lp.setUserName ( username ) ;
    logger.info("username entered");
    lp.setPassword ( password ) ;
    //log.**info**("password is entered");
    lp.clickSubmit ( ) ;
    
    if ( driver.getTitle ( ) . equals ( "EveryCred"))
    {
    Assert.assertTrue ( true ) ;
    }
    else
    {
    Assert.assertTrue ( false ) ;
    }
    //log.info("login testcase is passed");
```

Comment: Are you certain that `blocknet_maven_hybird_framework_v1.testcases.TC_login.logger` should be null and not set to something?

Comment: what we are required to do so that it won't show null???

Comment: I resolved this issue by adding "this":
before ----->>>> Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TC_login.class);
after---------->>>this. Logger.getLogger(TC_login.class);

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue, but its due to Initializing the Logger class second time.

First I declared it this way
"public static Logger log;"

But mistakenly re-intialized the class second time in body of method
"Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestBase.class);"

Fix : Removing second time declaration -
"log = Logger.getLogger(TestBase.class);"

Comment: Loggers should be `final`. This way you can not reinitialize it.

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced the same issue but without double declaration... just the code was put in the main() just after window.setVisible(true)... meaning the logger was not initialized. Just writing the things in the right order solved the issue :

- log.getLogger...
- window.setVisible
  ...